# Changing the time in an NSDate

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have a NSDate variable which is in the format of `2015-11-01 00:00:00 +0000\n` and I have a string variable which is my time in the format of `HH.mm`. I want to be able to add change the time in the NSDate so the date will become something like this as an example: `2015-11-01 09:45:00 +0000\n`.

Can someone show how it is done, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
let date = NSDate(string: "2015-11-01 00:00:00 +0000")
let formater = NSDateFormatter()
formater.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let time = formater.dateFromString("09:45")
let timeRef = formater.dateFromString("00:00")
let ti = time!.timeIntervalSinceDate(timeRef!)
let result = date!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(ti)
result.description  // "2015-11-01 09:45:00 +0000"
```

in real code, don't use implicit unwrapping ...